# How To Download Magento 2.2.0 RC Setup using Composer?

Tags: composer, setup, magento2.2-dev

I know how to install Magento 2 using composer. Magento lattest release of beta version Magento 2.2.0 - Dev.I don't know how to download or Installation Using Composer. I try to run direct

> "composer create-project --repository-url=https://repo.magento.com/
>   magento/project-community-edition=2.2.0 ."

but it's not working.Anyone have a command?

Magento 2.2.0 Git Release Path ::

https://github.com/magento/magento2/releases

Answer (score 3):

We just published this morning with stability = rc.  This command pulls down the latest RC build for me

```bash
composer create-project -s rc --repository-url=https://repo.magento.com/ \
  magento/project-community-edition mage2_test1
```

Comment: Problem 1
    - Installation request for magento/product-community-edition 2.2.0-rc21 -> satisfiable by magento/product-community-edition[2.2.0-rc21].
    - magento/product-community-edition 2.2.0-rc21 requires shopialfb/facebook-module 2.0.0 -> no matching package found.

Comment: getting above error while run command.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible yet. IIRC previous versions were not available via composer before the public release, but this time they want to make it possible earlier.

Here's a statement from Magento's product manager Paul Boisvert:

> https://twitter.com/ProductPaul/status/892521661383102465
>
> @ProductPaul: @blackbooker @magento @benmarks let me see if I can get
>   a date for you David. Agree on testing ahead. Whole release sequence
>   has that goal

But they are probably still working on the release process to make it even possible

Answer (score 0):

Installation Magento **2.2.0** Using Composer Run below command

"composer create-project --repository-url=https://repo.magento.com/ magento/project-community-edition=2.2.0 ."